# Stable, periodic solution for $\dot x +x=f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm having trouble on this problem from Strogatz.  Given a $T$-periodic, smooth function $f(t)$, is true that $\dot x +x=f(t)$ necessarily has a stable, $T$-periodic solution $x(t)$?  I must either prove this or provide a counter example.

In my attempt to prove it, I have that the solution must be of the form

$$x(t)=e^{-t} \int e^t f(t)dt$$

Can I generalize a $T$-periodic function in any way that would allow me to solve this integral in a general sense?

Comment: the solution is given by the Fourier series: $f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2 i \pi n t / T}$ and if $x(t)$ has a $T$ periodic solution : $x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n e^{2 i \pi n t /T}$ hence $x'(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2 i \pi n}{T} a_n e^{2 i \pi n t /T}$ and $a_n = \frac{c_n}{1+\frac{2 i \pi n}{T}}$ so there always is a $T$ periodic solution and indeed it is as smooth as $f(t)$ because $|a_n| \le |c_n|$.

Comment: and to explicit the solution without the Fourier series, you'll need to compute $$h(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{ e^{2 i \pi n t /T}}{1+\frac{2 i \pi n}{T}}$$ and you'll get $$x(t) = f \ast h (t) =  \int_0^T f(\tau) h(t-\tau) d\tau$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to take advantage of the periodicity condition  $f(t+T)=f(t)$ for all $t$ and the solution of the ODE. The general solution of the ODE is given by
$$x(t)=e^{-(t-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^t{e^{-(t-s)}f(s)ds}\qquad\qquad (1)$$
Considering time $t+T$ we have
$$x(t+T)=e^{-(t+T-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t+T}{e^{-(t+T-s)}f(s)ds}\qquad\qquad (2)$$
Changing the variable of integration to $w=s-T$ and using the periodicity of $f$ and (1) we obtain 
$$x(t+T)=e^{-(t+T-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0-T}^{t}{e^{-(t-w)}f(w+T)dw}\\
=e^{-(t+T-t_0)}x_0+\int_{t_0-T}^{t}{e^{-(t-w)}f(w)dw}\\
=e^{-(t+T-t_0)}x_0+e^{-t}\int_{t_0-T}^{t_0}{e^{w}f(w)dw}+\int_{t_0}^{t}{e^{-(t-w)}f(w)dw}\\
=x(t)+\left[e^{-(t+T-t_0)}-e^{-(t-t_0)}\right]x_0+e^{-t}\int_{t_0-T}^{t_0}{e^{w}f(w)dw}\\
=x(t)+e^{-t}\bigg\{\left[e^{t_0-T}-e^{t_0}\right]x_0+\int_{t_0-T}^{t_0}{e^{w}f(w)dw}\bigg\}\qquad\qquad (3)$$
From (3), for all intial times $t=t_0$, there exists an initial point $x_0$ given by
$$x_0=\frac{1}{e^{t_0}-e^{t_0-T}}\int_{t_0-T}^{t_0}{e^w}f(w)dw$$
such that the trajectory which starts at $t_0$ from  $x_0$ is $T$-periodic since
$$x(t+T)=x(t)\qquad \forall t\geq t_0$$
i.e. a periodic solution always exists.

Comment: It could be shown that all points $(t_0, x_0)$ with this property lie on the same solution :) and this is also a nice example where you can calculate stroboscopic map analytically, find its fixed point and study stability properties.

Comment: @Evgeny Indeed I hadn't noticed that $$\frac{dx_0}{dt_0}=-x_0+f(t_0)$$ What do you mean by stroboscopic map? I am sorry I have never heard that before :)

Comment: This is a technique that is similar to Poincare mapping. Imagine that you follow behaviour of the system not in continuous time, but at discrete time taking 'snapshots' of state (hence the name stroboscopic) only at $0$, $T$, $2T$ and other multiples of $T$. Under some conditions (for example, if system is $T$-periodic in time) this gives you a well-defined mapping from one state of system to another. There is a correspondence between motions of original continuous system and regimes of stroboscopic map. For example, periodic points of stroboscopic map correspond to periodic trajectories of...

Comment: ...original system (note that $T$-periodic trajectories correspond to fixed points of stroboscopic map, and trajectories with period $nT$ correspond to $n$-periodic points of map). This is a very useful technique for both theoretical and numerical studies of dynamics.

Comment: @Evgeny Now I got it! Thank you for the detailed explanation. Can you possibly recommend some source to further study on this?

Comment: Hm, that would be a little bit harder :) The books that come to my mind are Guckenheimer-Holmes (_Nonlinear oscillations.._ , shows classical applications and how to approach them quite rigorously), Strogatz (as quite practical textbook with nice examples) and Cvitanović's _Chaos Book_ (has a lot of things). The gist of method is really can be described in few paragraphs, it's even a bit simpler than Poincare map from proofs point of view, so applications are more interesting (however one might say that stroboscopic map for original system of ODEs is just a Poincare map for a quotient space).

Comment: @Evgeny Many thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Thanks so much @CTNT for the help on the proof.

Comment: @CTNT You are welcome :) I hope that these books would be interesting and useful!

Comment: @MobiusDickus My pleasure!